# Ubuntu fails to boot due to GNOME display manager error

Tags: ubuntu, boot, gnome, grub, gnome-shell

Ubuntu version: 22.04 last I checked, never upgraded

I use XFCE on Ubuntu as my desktop environment but I have to enter my credentials through GNOME's login screen before I can use XFCE. Today I was browsing a pretty cpu intensive site on Firefox that caused it to crash, and then it wasn't launching again when I tried. Crash reporter couldn't get any details about the crash and so I rebooted my computer.

It got stuck on uefi booting screen (just the lenovo and ubuntu logos and a loading spinner) for a very long time and didn't boot. I pressed ESC to view the system logs stuff and this is the output:
[image: error messages about gnome display manager]

It seems something happened to GNOME that prevents it from starting.

I have a live usb but I'm not sure what to do to fix the above.

Edit: As requested by @EdgarMagallon here is the output of:

- `sudo systemctl status gdm.service`
  [image: output from systemctl status of gdm]
- `sudo journalctl -xeu gdm.service`
  [image: output from journalctl of gdm]

Comment: Try pressing  `ctrl+alt+f#` where `#` is a number from 1 to 7 (or maybe you have more virtual consoles in activated state). For example, try `ctrl+alt+f1` and let me know if you get a shell prompt.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Ctrl + Alt + F5 brought up a shell which asked for my login info. I loginned and it lets me do bash commands. ls shows that it's running in the /home folder.

Comment: Then after you login run this command: `sudo systemctl status gdm.service` and check de the logs. Also if you didn't get any helpful output then run the command: `sudo journalctl -xeu gdm.service` and read the logs

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue fixed itself. It might have something to do with me running `startx` from the shell but now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is booted and running, you can do anything. It's just the Desktop daemon that won't run. I recommend reinstalling Ubuntu *Vanilla*, with default configuration. Wipe your disk before you do so, and let the installer do the partitioning.

Use a local Drive to backup your data, or upload it to the cloud, [for example gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/).

Comment: Can't I reinstall the desktop daemon or reconfigure it to its default settings? I would rather not wipe my entire disk, there is too much data to backup online and no offline backup medium (~450GB).

Answer (score 1):

There are **2 causes** for this problem that ends with the message `Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...`:

1. **Too big log files in `/var/log` directory.**
2. **Disk full**

In the first case, in the `/var/log` folder, notice that some files are big and have the same size, for example,

- `messages.1`: **1.8 GB**
- `syslog.1`: **1.8 GB**
- `user.log.1`: **1.8 GB**.

In this case, even emptying the disk the problem continues. Some sources suggest not deleting these files, but just emptying it. This can be done in the terminal with the commands

```
$ > messages.1
$ > syslog.1
$ > user.log.1
```

If the disk is full, the fisrt case alone will not help, in this case you must access the disk through another partition or through an installer (bootable live USB) and empty the disk.

Comment: Isn't "Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen..." a completely normal message?  Plymouth being the thing that does the fancy boot screen and hides kernel and systemd messages.

Comment: @OskarSkog It is just for specifying the problem